# Text file export not in desired format/layout

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm a beginner programmer and am less than a week into learning VS. Any help and explanations are highly appreciated. I apologize if I am in the wrong place or did something (or didn't do something) to not post this properly.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyhvd5jz1mefcox/TextFile.zip?dl=0) is what I have so far.

Inside the zip is the VS Project and two text files. The one labelled "TextFile(wrong)" is what is outputting. The one labelled "TextFile(right)" is what I need.

There is also a build under "\TextFile\TextFile\bin\Debug\TextFile.exe"

As you can see, in the wrong one, every input returns to the next line.

I am not sure how to get it how I need and I don't know how to narrow my research down anymore.

I believe the fix comes down to btnExport_Click in ShapeFileMaker.cs. You'll see how I am using StreamWriter. I followed a tutorial and have yet to fully wrap my head around how it works.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code here or upload it to pastebin or gist.github.com and then post the link to it here. I won't touch a cloud link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your [WriteLineAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158562.aspx) with [WriteAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeasync.aspx) where appropriate. Also I think you went overboard with await & async there, unless you involve very large and/or slow network, the regular [WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ack4zyt(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Write](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce2kyyb4(v=vs.110).aspx) should work well. Alternatively, write them to [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) first before [writing the result to the file at once](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx).

Tips, next time when you don't understand why a built-in function works the way they are, just put your cursor there, press F1, your browser should take you to the corresponding MSDN page with quite complete explanation.

Comment: Thank you, your break down was very insightful and I got it working! Thank you also for the tip! It's amazing how many different ways you can write something but it can also be overwhelming because each user approaches things their own way and has their own opinion. Any other advice for building a foundation and moving forward?

Comment: Start with learning beginners' course in [Microsoft Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-16169) or [C# Yellow Books](http://www.csharpcourse.com/). When you're coding, lookup if someone's already doing the component of your task in StackOverflow or [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), check their approaches & critics. Happy learning!